# ink! Size of Values Not Known at Compile Time

Tags: ink

I'm getting a very weird error for all functions and structs of my ink! contract:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `DefaultEnvironment` cannot be known at compilation time
6 |         pub fn get_bid(&self) -> Option<Balance> {
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `DefaultEnvironment`  

note: required by a bound in `ink_env::call::CallBuilder`
 |
346 | pub struct CallBuilder<E, CallType, Args, RetType>
    |                        ^ required by this bound in `ink_env::call::CallBuilder`
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Set<Call<DefaultEnvironment>>` cannot be known at compilation time
pub fn get_bid(&self) -> Option<Balance> {
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `Set<Call<DefaultEnvironment>>`
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Set<Call<DefaultEnvironment>>` cannot be known at compilation time
    |
113 |         pub fn get_bids_made(&self) -> u32 {
    |                                        ^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `DefaultEnvironment`
```

and so on... (about 30 errors like this)

I'm sure that's something global that I'm missing but I can't figure it out using error messages. What might be the problem?

Comment: The reason was that I've been using a `members: Vec<AccountId>` in my storage struct. But it's really strange that this is not possible. Opening another question then.

Comment: As you found out here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3153/1824 it is possible to use `Vec<AccountId` in your storage struct, provided it is an `ink_prelude::vec::Vec`