# Vec<AccountId> breaks compilation of ink! contract

Tags: ink, address

In my contract I want to store addresses of all users who called a specific function of the contract. For that purpose I use

```
    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Postbox {
        --snip--
        // Accounts of members;
        members: Vec<AccountId>,
        --snip--
    }
```

storage struct.

But at compile time it throws about 30 errors like:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `__ink_EventBase` cannot be known at compilation time

   |
8  | #[ink::contract]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `__ink_EventBase`
```

I figured out that this `members` vector was causing it. I've changed contained type from `AccountId` to just `i32` and the error was still there.
Does it mean that I can't use `Vec` in storage? Why?
What should I use instead then?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I just had to explicitely import `ink_prelude::vec::Vec` for that.